# get previous scope in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is there a better way than this one to get the previous scope from an ng-repeat inside a directive?

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">      
   <div my-directive> item {{ $index }} </div>    
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {

    restrict : 'A',
    link : function(scope){

       //Get scope of previous item
       var previousScopeText = scope.$parent.items[scope.$index - 1].val();

    }

  };

});
```

The purpose is to get it faster and not to pass trough the parent.

Any ideas?

Comment: On a higher level what are you trying to do in the first place? Example shown is far too simplified for meaningful discussion.  What does `faster` mean?

Comment: Make fiddle or Plunkr so that we can understand your question easily.